# Can´t reach Jquery function

Tags: jquery

Learning a tuto I am testing jquery features, one of the first is doing a button which goes back in browser´s history. I coded by javascript and everything was allright, but in jquery I can´t reach the function and I can´t figure it out.

I added the jquery library to the head of my page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

I created a new js file and I added to my head project as well:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/funciones.js"></script>
```

I added an ID and Name to my button:

```
<button id="BBack" name="BBack">Volver</button>
```

I added to my new created js file this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#BBack').click(function () {
        alert("aaaa");
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am, even, not getting the alert code in run time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Do you have multiple `#BBack` elements in the DOM? Have you include jQuery *before* your `funciones.js` file?

Comment: Have you checked network tab in dev tools, to confirm that jQuery was loaded. I'n not sure if you can load script from `~/` path

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan was right. I place funciones before jquery, stupid one. Sorry if I bother you all...

Answer (score 0):

Is this page loads successfully in browser and it's loading all JS files? For giving scripts folder as relative to current directory, you shouldn't use '~' here.

```
<< <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
>> <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

and the same goes for other JS file as well. If it's still not working, share the web page (or put it in codepen/jsfiddle etc.,) and it will be easier for others to review and comment.

Comment: Thanks @Ravindran. The problem was the order how I am loading the files... :S